# Sending file to server from a HTML input file

Tags: javascript, java, url, base64

I have a web page where I upload file from an input type file HTML element.
Then I need to send that file by Url with Ajax to a Java server to a REST web service where it will be processed.

I tried FileReader().readAsDataURL function in javascript, file is encoded in base64 then sent to server by url. But when I try to decode it in Java, it fails.

How can I achieve this ?

My code client-side :

```
var file = document.getElementById('add_attach').files[0];
var filename = document.getElementById('add_attach').value;

if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var name = encodeURIComponent(filename);
        var file_content = e.target.result;
         //Ajax request to server with sending file_content
    };
}
```

My code server-side :

```
file_content = file_content.substring(file_content.indexOf("base64"));
file_content = file_content.replace("base64,", "");
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(file_content);
```

The errror I get :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
```

Comment: If your form only has the file field, you can use `FormData` in your request. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: On the server, can you print or log the contents of `file_content` ?

Comment: @Ayrton can I send a FormData with Ajax in url ? but server-side, how do I get it ? which java variable can receive a FormData ?

Comment: @Arno it really depends on the framework you're using. But usually receiving a `FormData` is the same as receiving a regular form. You just add the `FormData` object to your ajax request in the place of the data to send

Comment: @Jamie yes I dit it in a text file

Comment: @Amo, what does it look like?  Can you attach it here?  Does it look like what you expect?

Comment: @Jamie if I encode the same file in base64 with Java and then I compare with the javascript base64, they are different. Some extras blanks for the javascript, not the same end. So maybe I must use another decode function in Java ?